# Errors in c++ code and how to fix them

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have one little problem with some code in C++
It won't compile, my skills in programing aren't too high right now,
if you could help me I would be thankful.
Ty in advance.

The question is WHERE are the errors, and HOW to fix the code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct S {
      S(int i){ this->x = i;}
      ~S(){}
    int x;
    static const int sci = 200;
    int y = 999; 
}
void main(){
    S *ps = new S(300);
    ps->x = 400;

    S s;
    s.x = 500;
}
```

compiler output:

```
8   13  [Warning] non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
9   1   [Error] expected ';' after struct definition
10  11  [Error] '::main' must return 'int'
In function 'int main()':
14  7   [Error] no matching function for call to 'S::S()'
14  7   [Note] candidates are:
4   7   [Note] S::S(int)
4   7   [Note] candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
3   8   [Note] S::S(const S&)
3   8   [Note] candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

======== AFTERMATCH ;) ===========

code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct S {
    S() : x() {}       // default constructor
    S(int i) : x(i) {} // non-default constructor
    ~S(){} // no need to provide destructor for this class
    int x;
    static const int sci = 200;
    int y = 999; // Only valid since C++11
}; // ; after class definition.
int main(){
    S *ps = new S(300);
    ps->x = 400;

    S s;
    s.x = 500;
}
```

as well as:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct S {
    S(int i){
        this->x = i;
    }
    ~S(){}
    int x;
    static const int sci = 200;
    int y = 999;
};
int main(){
    S *ps = new S(300);
    ps->x = 400;
    S *s = new S(20);
    s->x = 500;
}
```

worked!
TY to juanchopanza, Paul Renton and all others who spared their time to help me with this!

Comment: Com'n, give us the compiler messages at least...

Comment: Looks to me like your using a struct when you should be using a class

Comment: my fault!

8 13 [Warning] non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
9 1 [Error] expected ';' after struct definition
10 11 [Error] '::main' must return 'int'
In function 'int main()':
14 7 [Error] no matching function for call to 'S::S()'
14 7 [Note] candidates are:
4 7 [Note] S::S(int)
4 7 [Note] candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
3 8 [Note] S::S(const S&)
3 8 [Note] candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided

Comment: you forgot the semicolon at the end of the struct

Comment: @Scott only difference between a class and a struct is default accessibility(private vs public)

Comment: The first number of each error is the line number, and the second number of each error is how many letters over on the line it is.  That gives you the _exact_ location of the error.

Comment: @aryjczyk I see, thats useful to know. I was taught structs only held variables and classes had variables and functions. Although it wasn't the greatest teacher. Is there any reason you would use a struct over a class? for example in this situation?

Comment: @typ1231
thanks! Less errors now ;)

only 1

    4 2 [Error] expected unqualified-id before '{' token

Comment: @Scott, It can convey your intent, though I like using `struct` and having my public stuff first without the extra line. C only had `struct` for POD.

Comment: @JędrzejKopecki I'm pretty sure you put it at the wrong location. Please have a look at the answers here or read a book about C++.

Comment: @JędrzejKopecki: [I don't get that error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=345d20d8d8f2fc0587ca505ce61d767d-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51)

Comment: @chris Okay, thanks for clearing that up. Learn something new everyday :D I learnt C before I started C++, so thats probably why the concept of having more than data in a struct is new to me.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have declared a non-default constructor, the compiler no longer generates one for you. So you need to provide a default one. It is needed for this line.

```
S s;
```

You should also use the constructor initialization lists, as in this annotated example

```
struct S {
    S() : x() {}       // default constrictor
    S(int i) : x(i) {} // non-default constructor
      ~S(){} // no need to provide destructor for this class
    int x;
    static const int sci = 200;
    int y = 999; // Only valid since C++11
}; // ; after class definition.
```

Your code uses one C++11 feature, namely initialization of a non-static data member at the point of declaration. For this, you need to pass the `-std+c++11` flag.

Also, `void main()` is not valid C++. `main()` has to return `int`.

Comment: Using: int main() won't hurt either.

Comment: He also ought to pass the `-std=c++11` flag

Comment: @FlorisVelleman, MooingDuck, thanks. There was more wrong with OP's code than I first noticed.

Answer (score 1):

Couple things of which the compiler errors also state

You must finish a struct declaration with a semi colon much like you would close a class definition.

So,

```
struct S {
  S(int i){ this->x = i;}
  ~S(){}
int x;
static const int sci = 200;
int y = 999; 
}; // add semi colon
```

Also, you provided a constructor so the compiler no longer generates a default one for you.

So,
    S s;
Is invalid and you need to provide a default constructor or provide a default value for x if one is not given.

```
struct S {
  S(int i = 3){ this->x = i;} // Add a default value
  ~S(){}
int x;
static const int sci = 200;
int y = 999; 
};
```

**Edit: Suggested by millsj**

Also,
You will want to use -std=c++11 flag if you want to set defaults inside your struct

```
int y = 999; // Only valid in C++11
```

Lastly,

You want to return int with main, **not** void.

```
int main() // not void main()
```

Hopefully this all helps! We were all beginners at one point.

Comment: Also `int y = 999` is only valid in `C++11`

Comment: Good catch. I actually ran the code modifications on xcode and it didn't generate the c++11 error. Maybe Xcode is smart enough to add -std=c++11. Making an edit to include your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct S {
      S(int i){ this->x = i;}
      ~S(){}
    int x;
    static const int sci = 200;
    int y = 999; //<-- c++11, use the -std=c++11 flag on the compiler command line.
}; //<-- need a semicolon
int main(){ //<-- main must return int
    S *ps = new S(300);
    ps->x = 400;

    S s(500); //<-- must supply parameter since there is no default constructor.
    s.x = 500;

    delete ps; //<-- need to delete memory allocated with `new`

    return 0; //<-- main must return int
}
```

That looks like the errors that are listed. If you fix these and recompile there might be more.